# Amazon S3 bucket storage volume limit (in GB) through aws-sdk javascript or from aws-console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any feature in an Amazon S3 bucket to limit storage volume(IN GB)? If Yes then how can we set the Amazon S3 bucket storage volume limit (in GB) through AWS-SDK javascript or directly from AWS-console?

Answer (score 2):

There is no existing S3 feature to do this, so you have to create your custom solution. One way to monitor and limit the bucket size is to create a [CloudWatch alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html). As the bucket size grows, when it reaches your set limit, the state of your CloudWatch alarm will be changed to `ALARM`. Then it will send a message to SNS topic. You can create a Lambda function to subscribe to this SNS topic. In this Lambda function, you can block any subsequent uploads, for example, by updating bucket policy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the above-mentioned feature available in any other storage service like Google Cloud Storage if you know?

Comment: Nice solution. Just wonder if the function would have to calculate the bucket size but itself, or could S3 Inventory results be also used for that? This could be important for large buckets where calculation of their size could be time consuming?

Comment: @Vijay Sorry, I'm not familiar with other cloud storage services.

Comment: @Marcin No, the lambda doesn't need to calculate the bucket size. [S3 exports those metrics to CloudWatch daily](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html). So all the lambda function does is to get `BucketSizeBytes` metric.

Comment: @jellycsc Ah yes. You are absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: @Marcin My pleasure ◡̈